# How do I create tooltips on image maps?

Tags: tooltip, dreamweaver, imagemap

Is there any way to define my image map areas so that a tooltip will pop up when the area is moused over?

I am editing my page in dreamweaver and I have tryed the spry tooltips but the triggers won't assign to my polygon area.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

On the Area element of a Map you can specify both Title and Alt attribute. I would suggest setting both to the same text, since *some* older browsers have been known to mis-implement the spec for these.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp

Comment: This does not explain how to get a tooltip.I already have a title and alt attribute and I have tried assigning the trigger to both